# Interpretation of a column in SQL Server profile trace

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, profiler, trace

In a trace table generated by Profiler I tried to determine the origin of a lock using the column ObjectID2 joined to sys.allocation_units.

The results are not good. It identifies many tables that are NOT on the query that generated the trace.

Anyone knows what is that column means? My Google-fu failed me today.

The base query I used to find the object (the final one does not have the `au.*, p.*`
part):

```
select object_name(p.object_id) AS name, tt.RowNumber, au.*, p.* 
from 
  Trc_Tables_20131210 tt
  INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units au
    ON tt.ObjectID2 = au.allocation_unit_id  AND tt.ObjectID = 0
  INNER JOIN sys.partitions p
    ON au.container_id = p.hobt_id

WHERE au.type IN (1,3) AND tt.EventClass = 24
```

EDIT: The system health is a good indication of study. But for now I have to restrain myself to an SQL profiler trace table to study the locks of the query as I don't have easy access to customer's production server.
About the trace: the main event in trace is the Lock:Acquired.

Comment: This read is of interest to you: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/sql-server-2008-partition-level-lock-escalation-details-and-examples/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object ID is actually a partition id. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/354035/847990) over on SO provides a simple query to retrieve the needed information.

A side note, since you are using SQL Server 2008 R2 I would highly suggest taking a look into the [System Health](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877955.aspx) session that contains the recent deadlocks that have occurred, among other things. Depending on the activity of your instance you may need to pull this information out on a scheduled basis since it is buffer memory so does not stay there long. It is much more efficient to pull this information out than trying to setup a trace and waiting for it to occur again.

I actually wrote up a blog post on this area that includes a script to parse out the information where it is a bit more readable. The blog post [is here](http://meltondba.wordpress.com/2013/10/10/xml-glad-that-is-over/), the script is below:

```
;WITH xDeadlock (Contents)
AS
(
select CAST(XEventData.XEvent.value('(data/value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as xml) as DeadlockGraph
FROM
    (select CAST(target_data as xml) as TargetData
    from sys.dm_xe_session_targets st
    join sys.dm_xe_sessions s on s.address = st.event_session_address
    where name = 'system_health') AS Data
CROSS APPLY TargetData.nodes ('RingBufferTarget/event[@name="xml_deadlock_report"]') AS XEventData (XEvent)
), Victims AS
(
SELECT    ID = Victims.List.value('@id', 'varchar(50)')
FROM xDeadlock
CROSS APPLY xDeadlock.Contents.nodes('//deadlock/victim-list/victimProcess') AS Victims (List)
), Locks AS
(
SELECT  --xDeadlock.DeadlockID,
        MainLock.Process.value('@id', 'varchar(100)') AS LockID,
        OwnerList.Owner.value('@id', 'varchar(200)') AS LockProcessId,
        REPLACE(MainLock.Process.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)'), 'lock', '') AS LockEvent,
        MainLock.Process.value('@objectname', 'sysname') AS ObjectName,
        OwnerList.Owner.value('@mode', 'varchar(10)') AS LockMode,
        MainLock.Process.value('@dbid', 'INTEGER') AS Database_id,
        MainLock.Process.value('@associatedObjectId', 'BIGINT') AS AssociatedObjectId,
        MainLock.Process.value('@WaitType', 'varchar(100)') AS WaitType,
        WaiterList.Owner.value('@id', 'varchar(200)') AS WaitProcessId,
        WaiterList.Owner.value('@mode', 'varchar(10)') AS WaitMode
FROM    xDeadlock
        CROSS APPLY xDeadlock.Contents.nodes('//deadlock/resource-list') AS Locks (list)
        CROSS APPLY Locks.List.nodes('*') AS MainLock (Process)
        CROSS APPLY MainLock.Process.nodes('owner-list/owner') AS OwnerList (Owner)
        CROSS APPLY MainLock.Process.nodes('waiter-list/waiter') AS WaiterList (Owner)
), Process AS 
(
-- get the data from the process node
SELECT  --xDeadlock.DeadlockID,
        [Victim] = CONVERT(BIT, CASE WHEN Deadlock.Process.value('@id', 'varchar(50)') = ISNULL(Deadlock.Process.value('../../@victim', 'varchar(50)'), v.ID) 
                                     THEN 1
                                     ELSE 0
                                END),
        [LockMode] = Deadlock.Process.value('@lockMode', 'varchar(10)'), -- how is this different from in the resource-list section?
        [ProcessID] = Process.ID, --Deadlock.Process.value('@id', 'varchar(50)'),
        [KPID] = Deadlock.Process.value('@kpid', 'int'), -- kernel-process id / thread ID number
        [SPID] = Deadlock.Process.value('@spid', 'int'), -- system process id (connection to sql)
        [SBID] = Deadlock.Process.value('@sbid', 'int'), -- system batch id / request_id (a query that a SPID is running)
        [ECID] = Deadlock.Process.value('@ecid', 'int'), -- execution context ID (a worker thread running part of a query)
        [IsolationLevel] = Deadlock.Process.value('@isolationlevel', 'varchar(200)'),
        [WaitResource] = Deadlock.Process.value('@waitresource', 'varchar(200)'),
        [LogUsed] = Deadlock.Process.value('@logused', 'int'),
        [ClientApp] = Deadlock.Process.value('@clientapp', 'varchar(100)'),
        [HostName] = Deadlock.Process.value('@hostname', 'varchar(20)'),
        [LoginName] = Deadlock.Process.value('@loginname', 'varchar(20)'),
        [TransactionTime] = Deadlock.Process.value('@lasttranstarted', 'datetime'),
        [BatchStarted] = Deadlock.Process.value('@lastbatchstarted', 'datetime'),
        [BatchCompleted] = Deadlock.Process.value('@lastbatchcompleted', 'datetime'),
        [InputBuffer] = Input.Buffer.query('.'),
        xDeadlock.[Contents],
        [QueryStatement] = Execution.Frame.value('.', 'varchar(max)'),
        TranCount = Deadlock.Process.value('@trancount', 'int')
FROM    xDeadlock
        CROSS APPLY xDeadlock.Contents.nodes('//deadlock/process-list/process') AS Deadlock (Process)
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT Deadlock.Process.value('@id', 'varchar(50)') ) AS Process (ID)
        LEFT JOIN Victims v ON Process.ID = v.ID
        CROSS APPLY Deadlock.Process.nodes('inputbuf') AS Input (Buffer)
        CROSS APPLY Deadlock.Process.nodes('executionStack') AS Execution (Frame)
)
-- get the columns in the desired order
SELECT  p.Victim,
        p.LockMode,
        LockedObject = NULLIF(l.ObjectName, ''),
        l.database_id,
        l.AssociatedObjectId,
        LockProcess = p.ProcessID,
        p.KPID,
        p.SPID,
        p.SBID,
        p.ECID,
        p.TranCount,
        l.LockEvent,
        LockedMode = l.LockMode,
        l.WaitProcessID,
        l.WaitMode,
        p.WaitResource,
        l.WaitType,
        p.IsolationLevel,
        p.LogUsed,
        p.ClientApp,
        p.HostName,
        p.LoginName,
        p.TransactionTime,
        p.BatchStarted,
        p.BatchCompleted,
        p.InputBuffer
FROM    
    Locks l
    JOIN Process p ON p.ProcessID = l.LockProcessID
--WHERE p.TransactionTime > '2013-10-01'
ORDER BY p.Victim DESC,
        p.ProcessId;
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning System Health. It records deadlock events by default - learned at PASS Summit 2013 attending Jonathan's session.

Comment: @Shawn I hate to kill someone's joy but your wonderful script is not working on sql 2014, master database. Msg 9421, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
XML parsing: line 5, character 60, illegal name character

Comment: @marcellomiorelli It is not going to because Extended Events XML changed with in 2012. This query only works for SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @ShawnMelton that's a very useful script, when you have some time please, consider getting a sql 2014 version rolling

Comment: @marcellomiorelli you are more than welcome to ask a new question specific to that version of SQL Server, just link to this one.