# Extended Events XML query to show relevant info about deadlocks - SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, deadlock, extended-events

While trying to get together information about deadlocks I came across this link which asks a question regarding a trace:

[Interpretation of a column in SQL Server profile trace](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54810/interpretation-of-a-column-in-sql-server-profile-trace/54812?noredirect=1#comment207407_54812)

The answer dealt with reading data from the Extended Events, and uses XML.
It happens that the Extended Events XML changed and this script on [this blob](https://meltondba.wordpress.com/2013/10/10/xml-glad-that-is-over/) no longer works for any version after SQL Server 2008.

Is there a possibility, that we could have [this script](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54810/interpretation-of-a-column-in-sql-server-profile-trace/54812?noredirect=1#comment207407_54812) working for SQL Server 2014?

When I run the script on sql 2014, I get the error message below:

[image]

A copy of the script in question, from [Shawn Melton](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/507/shawn-melton) is here:

```
;WITH xDeadlock (Contents)
AS
(
select CAST(XEventData.XEvent.value('(data/value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as xml) as DeadlockGraph
FROM
    (select CAST(target_data as xml) as TargetData
    from sys.dm_xe_session_targets st
    join sys.dm_xe_sessions s on s.address = st.event_session_address
    where name = 'system_health') AS Data
CROSS APPLY TargetData.nodes ('RingBufferTarget/event[@name="xml_deadlock_report"]') AS XEventData (XEvent)
), Victims AS
(
SELECT    ID = Victims.List.value('@id', 'varchar(50)')
FROM xDeadlock
CROSS APPLY xDeadlock.Contents.nodes('//deadlock/victim-list/victimProcess') AS Victims (List)
), Locks AS
(
SELECT  --xDeadlock.DeadlockID,
        MainLock.Process.value('@id', 'varchar(100)') AS LockID,
        OwnerList.Owner.value('@id', 'varchar(200)') AS LockProcessId,
        REPLACE(MainLock.Process.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)'), 'lock', '') AS LockEvent,
        MainLock.Process.value('@objectname', 'sysname') AS ObjectName,
        OwnerList.Owner.value('@mode', 'varchar(10)') AS LockMode,
        MainLock.Process.value('@dbid', 'INTEGER') AS Database_id,
        MainLock.Process.value('@associatedObjectId', 'BIGINT') AS AssociatedObjectId,
        MainLock.Process.value('@WaitType', 'varchar(100)') AS WaitType,
        WaiterList.Owner.value('@id', 'varchar(200)') AS WaitProcessId,
        WaiterList.Owner.value('@mode', 'varchar(10)') AS WaitMode
FROM    xDeadlock
        CROSS APPLY xDeadlock.Contents.nodes('//deadlock/resource-list') AS Locks (list)
        CROSS APPLY Locks.List.nodes('*') AS MainLock (Process)
        CROSS APPLY MainLock.Process.nodes('owner-list/owner') AS OwnerList (Owner)
        CROSS APPLY MainLock.Process.nodes('waiter-list/waiter') AS WaiterList (Owner)
), Process AS 
(
-- get the data from the process node
SELECT  --xDeadlock.DeadlockID,
        [Victim] = CONVERT(BIT, CASE WHEN Deadlock.Process.value('@id', 'varchar(50)') = ISNULL(Deadlock.Process.value('../../@victim', 'varchar(50)'), v.ID) 
                                     THEN 1
                                     ELSE 0
                                END),
        [LockMode] = Deadlock.Process.value('@lockMode', 'varchar(10)'), -- how is this different from in the resource-list section?
        [ProcessID] = Process.ID, --Deadlock.Process.value('@id', 'varchar(50)'),
        [KPID] = Deadlock.Process.value('@kpid', 'int'), -- kernel-process id / thread ID number
        [SPID] = Deadlock.Process.value('@spid', 'int'), -- system process id (connection to sql)
        [SBID] = Deadlock.Process.value('@sbid', 'int'), -- system batch id / request_id (a query that a SPID is running)
        [ECID] = Deadlock.Process.value('@ecid', 'int'), -- execution context ID (a worker thread running part of a query)
        [IsolationLevel] = Deadlock.Process.value('@isolationlevel', 'varchar(200)'),
        [WaitResource] = Deadlock.Process.value('@waitresource', 'varchar(200)'),
        [LogUsed] = Deadlock.Process.value('@logused', 'int'),
        [ClientApp] = Deadlock.Process.value('@clientapp', 'varchar(100)'),
        [HostName] = Deadlock.Process.value('@hostname', 'varchar(20)'),
        [LoginName] = Deadlock.Process.value('@loginname', 'varchar(20)'),
        [TransactionTime] = Deadlock.Process.value('@lasttranstarted', 'datetime'),
        [BatchStarted] = Deadlock.Process.value('@lastbatchstarted', 'datetime'),
        [BatchCompleted] = Deadlock.Process.value('@lastbatchcompleted', 'datetime'),
        [InputBuffer] = Input.Buffer.query('.'),
        xDeadlock.[Contents],
        [QueryStatement] = Execution.Frame.value('.', 'varchar(max)'),
        TranCount = Deadlock.Process.value('@trancount', 'int')
FROM    xDeadlock
        CROSS APPLY xDeadlock.Contents.nodes('//deadlock/process-list/process') AS Deadlock (Process)
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT Deadlock.Process.value('@id', 'varchar(50)') ) AS Process (ID)
        LEFT JOIN Victims v ON Process.ID = v.ID
        CROSS APPLY Deadlock.Process.nodes('inputbuf') AS Input (Buffer)
        CROSS APPLY Deadlock.Process.nodes('executionStack') AS Execution (Frame)
)
-- get the columns in the desired order
SELECT  p.Victim,
        p.LockMode,
        LockedObject = NULLIF(l.ObjectName, ''),
        l.database_id,
        l.AssociatedObjectId,
        LockProcess = p.ProcessID,
        p.KPID,
        p.SPID,
        p.SBID,
        p.ECID,
        p.TranCount,
        l.LockEvent,
        LockedMode = l.LockMode,
        l.WaitProcessID,
        l.WaitMode,
        p.WaitResource,
        l.WaitType,
        p.IsolationLevel,
        p.LogUsed,
        p.ClientApp,
        p.HostName,
        p.LoginName,
        p.TransactionTime,
        p.BatchStarted,
        p.BatchCompleted,
        p.InputBuffer
FROM    
    Locks l
    JOIN Process p ON p.ProcessID = l.LockProcessID
--WHERE p.TransactionTime > '2013-10-01'
ORDER BY p.Victim DESC,
        p.ProcessId;
```

This is a picture with a partial result set from the above scrip, run on sql server 2008.

[image]

Comment: So we don't have to construct a full repro, can you give a clue about what "no longer works" means?

Comment: The query runs without error for me, which leads me to believe that the XML is balking on something specific to your environment, e.g. a table named with an invalid character.

Comment: @AaronBertrand on sql 2014? I will have to double check but running it on a different server, which I will do in 30 min. I will let you know then.

Comment: Yes, on SQL Server 2014. But it returns an empty result set, so I'm not certain where the issue may be. It definitely *sounds* data-related, not version-related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012 the event XML output of Extended Events changed dramatically; enough where it broke any code used for SQL Server 2008. A write of this can be found by Jonathan Kehayias:
[Extended Events Changes in SQL Server 2012 – Event XML for XML data elements](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/extended-events-changes-in-sql-server-2012/)

You will need to change the CTE for `xDeadlock` to the following:

```
;WITH xDeadlock (Contents)
AS
(
SELECT XEvent.query('(event/data/value/deadlock)[1]') AS DeadlockGraph 
FROM ( 
    SELECT XEvent.query('.') AS XEvent 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT CAST(target_data AS XML) AS TargetData 
        FROM sys.dm_xe_session_targets st 
        JOIN sys.dm_xe_sessions s ON s.address = st.event_session_address 
        WHERE s.name = 'system_health' AND st.target_name = 'ring_buffer' ) AS Data 
    CROSS APPLY TargetData.nodes ('RingBufferTarget/event[@name="xml_deadlock_report"]') AS XEventData ( XEvent ) 
    ) AS src
), Vicitims AS...
```

[image]

I moved the script from that blog post to my [GitHub repository and you can download it from here](https://gist.github.com/wsmelton/43888ac05b7eee5bce65a58ed941881a), have blog post scheduled for this morning with the link as well.